# Error with \numexpr in Tikzpgf

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw an 8*8 rectangular grid using Tikz and have the following code. But I get an error *"Package pgf Error: No shape named v18 is known"*. The bit of the code that is commented out works fine (horizontal lines). I see no reason why the rest should not work. Am I missing something basic?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    vertex/.style={draw,circle,thick,inner sep=0.25em}
  ]
    %Draw lattice
    \foreach \x in {0,...,7}{
      \foreach \y in {0,...,7}{
    \node[vertex] (v\x\y) at (\x,\y) {};
      }
    }  

    \foreach \x in {0,...,5}{
      \foreach \y in {0,...,5}{
%   \def\l{\the\numexpr\y+1}
    \def\m{\the\numexpr\x+1}
%   \draw (v\x\y) -- (v\x\l); %Horizontal lines
    \draw (v\x\y) -- (v\m\y); %Vertical lines
      }
    }


  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of `\the\numexpr` is to avoid defining new macros. Just use it *instead* of these macros.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    vertex/.style={draw,circle,thick,inner sep=0.25em}
  ]
    %Draw lattice
    \foreach \x in {0,...,7}{
      \foreach \y in {0,...,7}{
    \node[vertex] (v\x\y) at (\x,\y) {};
      }
    }  

    \foreach \x in {0,...,5}{
      \foreach \y in {0,...,5}{
    \draw (v\x\y) -- (v\x\the\numexpr\y+1); %Horizontal lines
    \draw (v\x\y) -- (v\the\numexpr\x+1\relax\y); %Vertical lines
      }
    }


  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you *really want* to define new macros, use

```
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\l{\y+1}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\m{\x+1}
```

or the `evaluate` key

```
\foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \m using {int(\x+1)}] in {0,...,5}{
  \foreach \y [evaluate=\y as \l using {int(\y+1)}] in {0,...,5}{
\draw (v\x\y) -- (v\x\l); %Horizontal lines
\draw (v\x\y) -- (v\m\y); %Vertical lines
  }
}
```

However, I would like to argue that not defining a new macro is the by far best option since you may overwrite previous definitions.

I also personally prefer to avoid using `\x` and `\y` since they have their own meaning in the `calc` syntax. Rather, I'd suggest to use `\X` and `\Y` instead

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    vertex/.style={draw,circle,thick,inner sep=0.25em}
  ]
    %Draw lattice
    \foreach \X in {0,...,7}{
      \foreach \Y in {0,...,7}{
    \node[vertex] (v\X\Y) at (\X,\Y) {};
      }
    }  

    \foreach \X in {0,...,5}{
      \foreach \Y in {0,...,5}{
    \draw (v\X\Y) -- (v\X\the\numexpr\Y+1); %Horizontal lines
    \draw (v\X\Y) -- (v\the\numexpr\X+1\relax\Y); %Vertical lines
      }
    }


  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was initially trying to use \numexpr, but I was unaware of the \relax command. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You want to `\edef`, rather than `\def`:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    vertex/.style={draw,circle,thick,inner sep=0.25em}
  ]
    %Draw lattice
    \foreach \x in {0,...,7}{
      \foreach \y in {0,...,7}{
    \node[vertex] (v\x\y) at (\x,\y) {};
      }
    }  

    \foreach \x in {0,...,5}{
      \foreach \y in {0,...,5}{
    \edef\l{\the\numexpr\y+1}
    \edef\m{\the\numexpr\x+1}
    \draw (v\x\y) -- (v\x\l); %Horizontal lines
    \draw (v\x\y) -- (v\m\y); %Vertical lines
      }
    }


  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]